# Configuring the slots in MAME for different hardware

Tags: emulation, apple, mame

How can you configure the [MAME emulator](http://mamedev.org/) for different hardware (hardware cards) in the available slots of the emulated system? For example, how can you put in different cards in the emulated Apple card slots?

(Background: I recently found out that MAME emulates the [Echo II speed synthesizer card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_2), but wasn't able to figure out how to make it work. I had to ask on the MAME IRC channel, because apparently this is documented nowhere, you need to ask, or you need to know ...)

Answer (score 9):

You can get information about command line options from the manpage, by using `-showusage` or `-showconfig` (which is explained to you after typing `mame -?`, `mame -h` or `mame -help`), or from the [online documentation](http://docs.mamedev.org/commandline/commandline-all.html).

So, from the commandline,

```
mame -listslots
```

shows the available slots per system, together with available options. What is not documented (yet) in any of the alternatives mentioned above is that every **slot name** can also be used as a **command line option**, so to configure MAME e.g. to use the Echo II card in Slot 1, type

```
mame -sl1 echoii ...
```

For the Apple, a few dozen cards are available.

Comment: For bonus points, reference the MAME docs website: http://docs.mamedev.org/commandline/commandline-all.html

Comment: @JohnBurger: you can get these with `-showusage` and on the man page, so no need for a web page. :-) Though they might update the webpage quicker in case they decide to document it ...

Comment: OK, so if you're not going to reference the webpage, how about adding that option to the answer?